# C++ Cout floating point problem

Tags: c++, floating-point

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        float s;
        s = 10 / 3;
        cout << s << endl;
        cout.precision(4);
        cout << s << endl;
        return 0;

}
```

Why the output does not show 3.333 but only 3 ??

Answer (score 6):

because you are doing integer division with `s = 10 / 3`

Try

```
s = 10.0f / 3.0f
```

Comment: Close, but now that's double.

Comment: I would have done the division as double. Let the compiler truncate only when it required (at the point of assignment).

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do a constant float division is:

```
s = 10.f / 3.f; // one of the operands must be a float
```

Without the `f` suffix, you are doing `double` division, giving a warning (from `float` to `double`).

You can also cast one of the operands:

```
s = static_cast<float>(10) / 3; // use static_cast, not C-style casts
```

Resulting in the correct division.

Answer (score 2):

10/3 is integer division. You need to use 10.0/3 or (float)10/3 or 10/3.0, etc.

Comment: Use C++ casts, like `static_cast`

Comment: Or ctor syntax, like `float(3)`